# mysql REGEXP not working in online version

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm developing a system that uses mysql REGEXP to find some rows.
In xampp localhost, that works good.
I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE departments REGEXP '\\D(7|1|2|3|4|5|6)\\D' LIMIT 0, 25
```

And it returns some rows that match my REGEXP.

This is `departments column` value of one of my `users` table rows that must match REGEX: `[1,3,4,6,7]`

With same database and same data in `users` table, I uploaded my project files and database, But it doesn't return any values.
I used to test my query in `Navicat Premium` directly, and again it was not returning any rows.
mysql version in my localhost is 4.6.5.2 and in my online version is 4.6.6.
Do you think I am forgetting something?
Any comments, offers, suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it without the LIMIT part?

Comment: @RealCheeseLord yes, doesn't make any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your pattern with

```
REGEXP '[^0-9][1-7][^0-9]'
```

`\D` is not supported and you can use a range in the bracket expression.

**Pattern details**

- `[^0-9]` - any char but digit
- `[1-7]` - a digit from `1` to `7`
- `[^0-9]` - any char but digit

If you need to also match at the start/end of string, use

```
REGEXP '(^|[^0-9])[1-7]($|[^0-9])'
```

The `(^|[^0-9])` group matches either start of string (`^`) or any char but a digit and `($|[^0-9])` matches any non-digit or the end of string (`$`).

Comment: It's working! thank you very much. I didn't know that \D is not supported! (And yet, my regex was working in my xampp localhost!!!!!). Anyway, you saved my day :D Thank you

Comment: @MahyarKhanbabaei PHP uses PCRE regex library, and MySQL `REGEXP` only supports a small range of POSIX regex possibilities.